# Spring Shared Custom Repository stating that no property found for sharedCustomMethod

Tags: java, spring

I am following Spring manual to create a Shared Repository to all my sub-repositories to provide more capability in the queries.

However, I am getting "No Property Found exceptions." Basically, I am following step 1.3.2 Adding custom behavior to all repositories from this link http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

I tried to change names and everything in the repos, however no luck.

Here is my code:

Interface

```
package com.ang.repository.common;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepositoryCustom<T, ID extends Serializable> extends     JpaRepository<T, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>  {
    void sharedCustomMethod(ID id);
    //Page<T> findAll(String relationship, Pageable paging);
}
```

Implemenation

```
package com.ang.repository.common;

public class BaseRepositoryCustomImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> 
        extends QueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID>
        implements BaseRepositoryCustom<T, ID> {

    public BaseRepositoryCustomImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }

    public void sharedCustomMethod(ID id) {
        // implementation goes here
    }

    @Override
    public Page<T> readPage(TypedQuery<T> query, Pageable pageable, Specification<T> spec) {
        return super.readPage(query, pageable, spec);
    }

//  @Override
//  public Page<T> findAll(String relationship, Pageable paging) {
//      return null;
//  }

}
```

First Repository

```
package com.ang.repository.core;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "alndomain", path = "alndomain")
@CrossOrigin(maxAge = 3600)
@Repository("customAlnDomainRepository")
public interface AlnDomainRepository extends BaseRepositoryCustom<AlnDomain, Long>{
    @Query(value="select * from #{#entityName} e where e.alnName = ?1",nativeQuery=true)
    List<AlnDomain> findAllByAlnDomain(String alnDomain);

    @Query(value="select * from #{#entityName} e where e.alnName = ?1 and e.name = ?2",nativeQuery=true)
    AlnDomain findOneByAlnDomainName(String alnDomain,String name);
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property sharedCustomMethod found for type AlnDomain!
```

I tried to remove the "Custom" from the naming convention, however no luck.

**Solution**

My factory bean in step 1.3.2 (Section 4) was not properly set. After debugging, I found out that Spring was not recognising the method as a Custom Method.

I added the following annotation to my main Spring Application class:

@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass=com.ang.repository.common.BaseRepositoryFactoryBean.class)

Everything is working.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the base repository implementation should be `BaseRepositoryImpl` instead of `BaseRepositoryCustomImpl` :

```
public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> 
        extends QueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID>
        implements BaseRepositoryCustom<T, ID> {

    public BaseRepositoryCustomImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }

    public void sharedCustomMethod(ID id) {
        // implementation goes here
    }

    @Override
    public Page<T> readPage(TypedQuery<T> query, Pageable pageable, Specification<T> spec) {
        return super.readPage(query, pageable, spec);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jean, thanks for the answer, however it didn't work in my case. I rewrote the  class to *public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends QueryDslJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BaseRepositoryCustom<T, ID>*, and still nothing. Same error: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property sharedCustomMethod found for type AlnDomain!

Comment: Jean, found the issue. My factory repository was not being instantiated. I had to add @EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass=com.ang.repository.common.BaseRepositoryFactoryBean.class) to the main Spring Application.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

My factory bean in step 1.3.2 (Section 4) was not properly being instantiated. After debugging, I found out that Spring was not recognising the method as a Custom Method. RepositoryFactorySupport from Spring was not instantiating the custom Factory Bean.

I added the following annotation to my main Spring Application class:

@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass=com.ang.repository.common.BaseRepositoryFactoryBean.class)

Everything is working.

Thanks all.